# How to get deserialize object when type discriminator element on root json object using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core, system.text.json

Sorry for my poor English.

I had success run code from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#support-polymorphic-deserialization). I got new JSON data and there is another problem.

The JSON data is defined like this:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "aaa",
    "typeDiscriminator": "search",
    "settingDataTemp": {
      "id": 11,
      "type": "11",
      "value": "11"
    }
}
```

And the POCO class is defined as:

```
public class RootContent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public PageModuleType typeDiscriminator { get; set; }
    public IPageSubContentSetting settingDataTemp { get; set; }
}
```

I want to deserialize `settingDataTemp` object, so the `JsonConverter` `Read` method like

```
public override IPageSubContentSetting Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    PageModuleType typeDiscriminator;
    string rawText;
    var discriminatorPropName = nameof(RootContent.typeDiscriminator);

    using (var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))
    {
        if (!jsonDocument.RootElement.TryGetProperty(discriminatorPropName, out var typeProperty))
        {
             throw new JsonException();
        }

        var result = Enum.TryParse(typeProperty.GetString(), true, out typeDiscriminator);

        if (!result)
        {
             throw new JsonException();
        }

        rawText = jsonDocument.RootElement.GetRawText();
     }
}
```

Can't get `typeDiscriminator` from `JsonDocument.RootElement` because it's defined on outer object.

Is there any way to get `typeDiscriminator` value?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem just use NewtonSoft.Json To edit JSON struct and copy `typeDiscriminator` value from root to `settingDataTemp` element.